# Why is implication used instead of conjunction in this instance of translating English into a logical statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic-translation

Can you please help me understand why implication was used instead of conjunction in the answer to this practice question? I have been struggling with nested quantifiers and when to use implication versus conjunction. I thought for sure this would be a case for conjunction. Thank you.

> Use predicates, quantifiers, logical connectives, and
> mathematical operators to express the statement that every positive integer is the sum of the squares of four integers.

#### my answer:

$$ \forall x \exists a \exists b \exists c \exists d ((x > 0) \land (x = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)) $$

#### correct solution from book:

$$ \forall x \exists a \exists b \exists c \exists d ((x > 0) \implies x = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2) $$

Comment: "Pick any number. If it happens to be positive, then I can express it thus."

Comment: Also: ["Every positive number is a sum of at most 4 integers"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4401470/21813)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you use $\to$ for $\forall$ and $\land$ for $\exists$. When there are multiple quantifiers, the choice of connective depends on which of the quantified variables the questionable connective should restrict. Here, you're restricting the domain of $x$ by requiring that $x > 0$. $x$ is universally quantified, so you need $\to$.

Comment: thank you very much. so this case is more of an exception, and we are using implication because x is being restricted without any relationship to a, b, c, d? for example, what if the question had the restriction: x > a, x > b, x > c, x > d? would the answer be first or second?


$$ \forall x \exists a \exists b \exists c \exists d ((x>a) \land (x>b) \land (x>c) \land (x>d) \land (x=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2))  $$


$$ \forall x \exists a \exists b \exists c \exists d (((x>a) \land (x>b) \land (x>c) \land (x>d)) \implies (x=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2))  $$

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think either phrasing is natural, but your phrasing is incorrect. I will take all quantifiers to range over the integers.

Let’s start with the statement “$x$ is the sum of four squares”. This is naturally translated as $\exists a \exists b \exists c \exists d (x = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)$.

Now we proceed to the slightly more complicated statement, “If $x$ is positive, then $x$ is the sum of four squares”. We know how to say “$x$ is positive”, and we know how to say “$x$ is the sum of four squares”. To make an “if” statement in logic, we use the implication operator. So this translates to $x > 0 \implies \exists a \exists b \exists c \exists d (x = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)$. It turns out that this is logically equivalent to saying $\exists a \exists b \exists c \exists d (x > 0 \implies x = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)$, at least in classical logic. It is not a particularly natural way of phrasing the underlying claim, however.

Finally, we want to say “For all $x$, if $x$ is positive, then $x$ is the sum of four squares”. To do this, we add the $\forall x$, and we’re done.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is asserting, among other things, that for every $x$, $x$ is positive.

The **official** solution is asserting that

for all $x$, 
there exists some combination of $a,b,c,d$ such that 
**if** $x$ is positive, 
**then** 
$x$ can be expressed in the satisfactory manner.

The **official** solution *should* be saying that

for all $x$, 
there exists some combination of **integers** $a,b,c,d$ such that 
**if** $x$ is a positive integer, 
**then** 
$x$ can be expressed in the satisfactory manner.